# Check if a specific point x,y is inside a rectangle

Tags: c#, geometry, point, rectangles

I'm trying to write program which specifies a rectangle via its width and height and its top and left corner point. I want the program to allow a user to input a point x,y after which my goal is to have the program determine whether the point is inside the rectangle.

Here is my code so far, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Can anyone help me with the implementation of `bool Rectangle.Contains(x, y)`?

```
public struct Rectangle
{
    // declare the fields
    public int Width;
    public int Height;
    public int Top;
    public int Left;

    // define a constructor
    public Rectangle(int Width, int Height, int Top, int Left)
    {
        this.Width = Width;
        this.Height = Height;
        this.Top = Top;
        this.Left = Left;
    }

    public bool Contains(int x, int y) { }
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Creating a Rectangle instance");
         Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle(6, 2, 1, -1);

         Console.WriteLine("myRectangle.Width = " + myRectangle.Width);
         Console.WriteLine("myRectangle.Height = " + myRectangle.Height);
         Console.WriteLine("myRectangle.Top = " + myRectangle.Top);
         Console.WriteLine("myRectangle.Left = " + myRectangle.Left);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at:  
http://math.stackexchange.com/q/190111/130682

Answer (score 5):

I haven't used the `System.Drawing.Rectangle` class before, but it looks to me that you could use the `Contains(Point)` method. Here is a link to that documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t27w02(v=vs.110).aspx

As you can see, the parameter passed to `Contains()` is of type `Point`. Create a variable of that type using the user-entered x,y values and pass it to the `Contains()` method. Here is a link to the `Point` structure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point(v=vs.110).aspx

When you view the documentation for `Point`, notice that off to the left there are several links to different ways to use points.

Comment: the new `System.Windows.Rect` (WPF) also has a `Contains` method : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.rect?view=netframework-4.8#methods

Comment: **Caution**: If you use `System.Drawing.Rectangle[F].FromLTRB()` to create your rectangle, remember that Rectangle is a device for drawing a UI and in UI the origin is in the top left. This means that T should be less than B in FromL**T**R**B**. If you specify a T that is greater than B you'll never get `Contains(x,y)` to work, because FromLTRB takes T as Y, and Contains uses `rectangle.Y <= y < (rectangle.Y+rectangle.Height)`

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing whether it's a right triangle or the orientation of the triangle, it's hard to give a precise answer, but the general approach I would use would be to get the angles between the vertices and the angles of the point versus each vertex. You can then use the angles to do a boundary check.